# Where do I start with distributed computing?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-computing

I'm interested in learning techniques for distributed computing. As a Java developer, I'm probably willing to start with [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/). Could you please recommend some books/tutorials/articles to begin with?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe you can read some papers related to MapReduce and distributed computing first, to gain a better understanding of it. Here are some I would like to recommand:

- MapReduce: Simplified Data Processing on Large Clusters, http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi04/tech/full_papers/dean/dean_html/
- Bigtable: A Distributed Storage System for Structured Data, http://www.usenix.org/events/osdi06/tech/chang/chang_html/
- Dryad: Distributed data-parallel programs from sequential building blocks, http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824-2007/papers/isard-dryad.pdf
- The landscape of parallel computing research: A view from berkeley, http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.67.8705&rep=rep1&type=pdf

On the other hand, if you want to know better of Hadoop, maybe you can start reading Hadoop MapReduce framework source code.

Answer (score 3):

Currently, bookwise I would check out - [Hadoop A Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521979). Its written by Tom White who has worked on Hadoop for a good while now, and works at Cloudera with Doug Cutting (Hadoop creator).

Also on the free side, Jimmy Lin from UMD has written a book called: [Data-Intensive Text Processing with MapReduce](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/MapReduce-book-final.pdf). Here's a link to the final pre-production verison (link provided by the author on his [website](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/book.html)).

Answer (score 2):

The All Things Hadoop Podcast http://allthingshadoop.com/podcast has some good content and good guests.  A lot of it is geared to getting started with Distributed Computing.

Answer (score 2):

[MIT 6.824](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.824/) is the best stuff. Only reading google papers related to Hadoop is not enough. A systematic course learning is required if you want to go deeper.

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop is not necessarily the best tool for all distributed computing problems. Despite its power, it also has a pretty steep learning curve and cost of ownership.
You might want to clarify your requirements and look for suitable alternatives in the Java world, such as [HTCondor](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/), [JPPF](http://www.jppf.org) or [GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com/) (my apologies to those I do not mention).

Answer (score 1):

Here are some resources from Yahoo! Developer Network

a tutorial:

http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/

an introductory course (requires Siverlight, sigh):

http://yahoo.hosted.panopto.com/CourseCast/Viewer/Default.aspx?id=281cbf37-eed1-4715-b158-0474520014e6

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to learn a distributed computing platform that is less complicated than Hadoop you can try Zillabyte. You only need to know some Ruby or Python to build apps on the platform.

As LoLo said, Hadoop is a powerful solution, but can be rough to start with.

For materials to learn about distributed computing try http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-824-distributed-computer-systems-engineering-spring-2006/syllabus/. There are several resources recommended by the course as well.